# Scheduled program VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I would like to ask for a recommendation for my project.

Basically, it's a scheduled program that shall run at a given period of time, for example,

6:00 pm daily, it includes importing an excel file and inserting it in a sql table.

I have my codes with me, but I dont know how to execute this program automatically.

can you give me some advice

I'm using MSSQL2005 server. And VB.NET language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build your application to an executable that just does the task once and use [Windows task scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).

Comment: Of all the different Timer answers that were possible, you had to ruin it with the only reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my old shop, we occassionally forgot about the one-off tasks running under Task SCheduler, but we had lots of SQL Agent jobs running nightly or weekly. So, just to keep things all together, we created SQL Agent jobs for things like this. So my answer is the same as Bala's, but I would trigger the app through a job on SQL Server instead.

How? Take a look at this: http://bp0.blogger.com/_mDuWqJiJyXE/SB6fy1yBRfI/AAAAAAAAATc/bmdxxAfFTjc/s1600-h/JS_Steps1.png

Answer (score 0):

You could use Visual Studio to create  windows service which performs the timed actions...it's a steeper learning curve though.